# Debug a subclass of TypedPageData in Episerver 6 R2

Tags: getter-setter, episerver, episerver-6-r2

I need to add a validator condition in a composer block (class) in  Episerver, so I started from this:

```
[PageType("110187CD-89F0-40A8-A075-68944DD5AC1D",

    Name = "New Composer Block", 

    Description = "My Description",

    Filename = "/Templates/Webform1.aspx")]

public class ComposerPage : ComposerPageBase

{

    [PageTypeProperty(

        DisplayInEditMode = false,

        UniqueValuePerLanguage = false,

        Type = typeof(LongString),

        Tab = typeof(ComposerTab))] 

    public virtual string MainArea { get; set; } 

}
```

and rewrote the accessor (getter and setter) part as:
.....

```
public virtual string MainArea
        {
            get { return this.GetPropertyValue(p => p.MainArea); }
            set { 
               if(conditionhere)
                    this.SetPropertyValue(p => p.MainArea, "abc");
               else this.SetPropertyValue(p => p.MainArea, value);
                }
        }
```

However, editing the page does not take into account my custom setter (it behaves as though I had a regular {get; set;} 
and moreover, the breakpoint on the setter can't be reached during debug! (quite unexpected and seems to relate to the inner workings on episerver/PTB).

So interested in:

- why a TypedPageData (in my example ComposerPageBase inherits from TypedPageData) can't be debugged as such
- what is an acceptable workaround for this? (needed in order to apply validation in the setter)

Answer (score 0):

With **PageTypeBuilder** the model type's getters and setters aren't invoked for retrieving/setting the property value when content is edited through the UI.

Instead it effectively uses the **Property** indexer.

This is different from how it works in Episerver 7+.

This is why your code isn't executed when that string property is edited in the UI. However, if you'd set the value through code, like `CurrentPage.MainArea = "Some value"`, your setter code would execute.

To clarify, this is because **PageTypeBuilder** is a third-party add-on, it's not the native behavior of Episerver 6. If your website was an Episerver 7+ website, you would be able to debug your code like you expected, as it features strongly-typed content models natively.